# Why doesn't "ping -vrf" works when ping works?

Tags: ping

```
0:root@SERVER:/root # ping IPADDRESS
PING IPADDRESS (IPADDRESS): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from IPADDRESS: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=0 ms
64 bytes from IPADDRESS: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=0 ms
64 bytes from IPADDRESS: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=0 ms
^C
--- IPADDRESS ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0/0/0 ms
0:root@SERVER:/root # ping -vrf IPADDRESS
PING IPADDRESS (IPADDRESS): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
ping: wrote IPADDRESS 64 chars, ret=-1
.ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
ping: wrote IPADDRESS 64 chars, ret=-1
.ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
ping: wrote IPADDRESS 64 chars, ret=-1
.ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
ping: wrote IPADDRESS 64 chars, ret=-1
.ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
ping: wrote IPADDRESS 64 chars, ret=-1
.ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
ping: wrote IPADDRESS 64 chars, ret=-1
.ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
```

**QUESTION**: If I can ping the IPADDRESS then why can't I "ping -vrf" the IPADDRESS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is because `-r` option. From man:

```
   -r     Bypass the normal routing tables and send directly to a host 
          on an attached interface.  If the host is not on a directly-
          attached network, an error is returned.  This option can be 
          used to ping a local host through an interface that has no 
          route through it provided the option -I is also used.
```

You need your host directly attached to your network, otherwise it will fail like in your question.